# File uploader doesn't work in Android but works in IOS

Tags: apex, visualforce, apexinputfield

I have a requirement where I have to upload the mobile photo into Account's object  under the Notes & Attachment section. For this I have written an Apex code where I used Input file tag , below is the snippet for the same

```
<apex:inputfile value="{!att.body}" fileName="{!att.Name}"></apex:inputfile>
```

Now the problem is, this inputfile tag is working fine with iOS.But the same doesn't work with Android (Input file window doesn't open).

Could you kindly help in fixing the issue. Revert for more information.

Comment: I faced that issue also,when do google I think Android got issue with input file.

Comment: What android version that you use?Is it 4.4?

Comment: I test some,it works in 4.2,4.3,5.0 but not 4.4